# Customizable inclusion of frames-slides from a huge Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I have one master-huge `beamer` presentation having lots of frames.

Depending on the audience I wish to customize, say, for lay audience I will just include basic slides, for experts I wish to include advanced slides. Not sure if there is such facility in Beamer already, but wish it could be as simple as :

- I will label each frame, with say, BASIC, ADVANCED , keywords like that...
- I should be able to compile, by saying `\includeonly{BASIC}`. This should include all slides marked BASIC.
- If I say `\includeonly{ADVANCED}`, only advanced slides should get compiled.
- Additionally, if I say, `\includeonly{BASIC, ADVANCED}`, everything will be included.

Comment: You've used the conditional tag; is there something more that you need that standard conditional statements `\if \else \fi \fi` could not achieve?

Comment: Is this question the same? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52569/output-different-beamer-presentations-from-same-tex-file.

Answer (score 0):

The `etoolbox` package could give you all the control you need, it would require adding a lot of `\iftoggle` statements if your master Beamer presentation is huge but it offers complete flexibility.

For example you might define your two logical variables `BASIC` and `ADVANCED`:

```
\newtoggle{BASIC}
\newtoggle{ADVANCED}

\toggletrue{BASIC}
\togglefalse{ADVANCED}
```

You could then use the following conditionals in your code:

```
% do some standard (or outline) material [e.g. title page, contents]

\iftoggle{BASIC}{%
    % do some basic material
}{}

\iftoggle{ADVANCED}{%
    % do some advanced material
}{}
```

This would then compile all your standard material AND basic material BUT NOT advanced material.